# How to tell how an External Library was added?

Tags: android, android-studio

My issue stems from the message:

> Attribute "textAllCaps" has already been defined

showing up in the Messages view when trying to run my app. I'm getting a few of these "has already been defined errors". I think it's because I have two versions of the support library under "External Libraries" in the Project view of Android Studio. I have appcompat-v7 and support-v4.

Now, I saw that one of my local library projects had a build.gradle file that declared support-v4 as a dependency, but now I removed it and I still get my error. I did a search for support-v4 and it's not located anywhere.

I think that if I'm able to find out what is causing something to be listed under "External Libraries" then I should be able to figure out why support-v4 is being added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quickly get this information on the command line with the `dependencies` command:

```
user@machine$ ./gradlew app:dependencies --configuration compile

:app:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Project :app
------------------------------------------------------------

compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1
+--- com.android.support:design:22.2.1
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1
\--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0
     \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.4.0

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.795 secs
```

This command is also available in the "gradle" tab on the right-hand side of the screen in Android Studio, listed in the "help" category.

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. This gave me a different issue than `Attribute "textAllCaps" has already been defined` so now I have to figure that out. The error from this command is more helpful than the messages output one though.

Comment: So it looks like google play services needs support-v4... any idea on how to use v7?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: I figured out my issue, but my badly worded question was just asking how to force GPS to use appcompat-v7 instead of v-4. Using the command you gave me, I saw the GPS actually depends on support-v4 (which I thought was the cause of my issue).

Comment: Cool, so your problem is fixed then?